# Move a point with known angle on a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles

Having a circle of radius $R$ with the center in $O(0, 0)$, a starting point on the circle (e.g. $(0, R)$) and an angle $\alpha$, how can I move the point on the circle with $\alpha$ degrees? I need to get the second point where it was moved.

### Example

> The red point is on $(0, R)$ and $\alpha$ is $90$ degrees. The violet circle is where the first point is supposed to be moved, and its coordinates are $(R, 0)$. Then we consider the violet point as starting point and move it with $45$ degrees. The new position will be where the blue circle is.
>
> [image]

Comment: Initially use Polar coordinate to express your initial point as $R cos \pi/2 , R sin \pi/2$ Then rotate the angle to desired position. Angles to clockwise are negative by convention.

Comment: @Mann Isn't it supposed to be $Rsinπ$ instead (without `/2`)?

Comment: $sin (\pi/2) =1 $ ^^ Your initial point i think from diagram is at $\pi / 2$

Comment: Btw,by $(\pi/2)$ I meant $\alpha $ and not the purple point. Purple point is that $0$ angle.

Comment: @Mann Got it! You're correct. Please post an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As you can see from the image, The point you require is at $-45 $ Degree from $0$ . So your required point is $R  \cos (-\pi /4), R \sin (-\pi/4)$

Which can be equivalently written as?

Comment: Can you please add a general formula where I have as input the initial point ($x$ and $y$), the radius $R$ and the angle? Maybe it would be nice to have support for different circle centers. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

well you can consider the following linear transformation given by:

T : $R^2$ $\rightarrow$ $R^2$

given by T(x,y) = (cos$\theta$x - sin$\theta$y,sin$\theta$x + cos$\theta$y).

This does what you asked rotates your point counter-clockwise about the origin.

Comment: In this solution, where does the $R$ value appear in the formula?

Comment: @IonicăBizău the R vanishes, as both points are on the same circle. But the result seems to be wrong, I believe it should be: $(\cos\theta x - \sin\theta y, \cos\theta y + \sin\theta x)$